# Boot Ubuntu 12 on Mac Mini with Lion OS

Tags: mac, install, unix, dual-boot

How can I boot Ubuntu-12.04 LTS on Mac Mini Lion Server (early 2011) with no CD reader?

Comment: I tried [Ask Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick) Ubuntu using USB drive? but it didn't work.

Comment: What didn't work with the USB install?

Comment: I am creating the boot-able USB on Ubuntu but when I try to boot form it Mac does not even show the USB as boot-able option.

Comment: Hey Woz, I got it now! [Download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and then make bootable USB [learn more](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) which works with Macbook, iMac and Mini etc.. (2011 and later versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Make a bootable Ubuntu flash drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)
2. Insert it in your computer
3. Hold Option key while booting
4. Select USB for boot
5. Install Ubuntu